# How to give type hint to a class that inherits from Generic class

Tags: python, python-typing

I have a Generic class in Python that is declared the following way:

```
class BaseClass(Generic[T]):
   def my_func(self):
      pass
```

There are 3 class that inherit from this Generic class:

```
class ClassA(BaseClass[Dog]):
   ...

class ClassB(BaseClass[Cat]):
   ...

class ClassC(BaseClass[Horse]):
   ...
```

Now I want to write a function with an argument that can be one of the 3 classes above.

I tried to write:

```
def my_func(my_arg: BaseClass):
   my_arg.my_func()
```

However, mypy throws the error:

```
 error: "BaseClass" not callable  [operator]
```

Do you have any idea what type hint to give to my_arg?

Comment: isn't it just `def my_func(my_arg: BaseClass[T]) -> None`?  if not could you give version numbers because I don't get errors under Python 3.10.6 & mypy 0.971.

Comment: Having just tried it (3.10 and latest mypy), I don't seem to get errors either.

Comment: fyi: strict checking mode, e.g. `mypy --strict foo.py`, can help with debugging type errors

Answer (score 1):

you can either use `Union` as mentioned in the answer above **[answer 1]**, or (in case you have a lot of classes) create a new typeVar **[answer 2]** :

answer 1 :

```
from typing import Union

def my_func(my_arg: Union[ClassA, ClassB, ClassC]):
    ...
```

answer 2 :

```
from typing import Union, NewType

GenericType = NewType('GenericType', Union[ClassA, ClassB, ClassC])

def my_func(my_arg: GenericType):
    ...
```

Comment: The argument to `NewType` must be a class, not an arbitrary type. In particular it can't be a union. I think you just want `GenericType = Union[ClassA, ClassB, ClassC]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from typing import Union


def my_func(my_arg: Union[ClassA, ClassB]):
    my_arg.my_func()
```

Comment: This would work, but probably isn't the best solution as with a large number of sub-classes it could get messy. That said, I'm not sure what the best solution is.

Comment: You are right about that indeed. With a large number of classes I'm not sure what the best solution would be

Comment: @HPringles This solution will definitely work, but I'm looking for a more generic solution.

Comment: Yeah exactly, I'm just having a play around now to see if I can make something work

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32571044)